# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "domain.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android

Bumped into an issue where my application using  https://github.com/square/okhttp - okhttp version - 3.12.1 is not able to connect to a domain even though I've provided the Internet Permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

The user was, however, able to connect to the internet on their device and use other apps, based on their review comments.

For now, I am unable to reproduce the exception and hence if anyone who has experienced this issue before could help me understand better.

I cannot upgrade the library at the moment as I don't want to introduce a big change.

Stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "domain.com": No address associated with hostname
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at okhttp3.Dns$-CC.lambda$static$0(SourceFile:39)
    at okhttp3.-$$Lambda$Dns$mTkNcZf2K4euny3_jks6Cac6Az0.lookup(Unknown Source:0)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(SourceFile:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(SourceFile:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(SourceFile:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(SourceFile:214)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(SourceFile:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(SourceFile:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
    at com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.a.a$a.intercept(SourceFile:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(SourceFile:264)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(SourceFile:93)

Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:200)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: On Windows: `ping domain.com -6` yields the same error. Not sure if your user needs an IPv6 address or not...

Comment: have you found the solution for this? if yes, please share I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Sometimes i've faced the issue if my domain was 'www.example.com', instead i usually add 'http://'  infront of 'www.example.com'

Comment: This happened to me when my emulator couldn't reach the internet.  I tried everything, eventually created a different emulator with SDK version 34.

Answer (score 0):

I usally have that error using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) (with Okhttp as client), it happens when the device doesn't have any internet conection (both WIFI or mobile data) or my server endpoint is down. Try it yourself! But there are several factors else; like [runtime request permisions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-request) or the [network security config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=es).

Hope this helps, bro.

Comment: the users affected by this issue state that they have an internet connection as they are able to use other apps. The server endpoint is also up and running with no errors hence iOS users are not affected. There are no network security config rules that are linked to the AndroidManifest.

Comment: I am facing similar issue did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by making a few DNS changes.

- Reduced few CNAME records.
- Reduced TTL.

No code changes were made on the android client.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the user's ISP it may occur, I think the best way to guarantee that the domain gets resolved is using a custom DNS Resolver using a Custom Caching mechanism based on the needs.
Sometimes ISPs/Routers cache the DNS response based on the first Query,
So most of the time you ask for the record from the primary DNS servers it works.
Take a look at https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-dns/

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question.
Referring to [this link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6903#issue-1047798625)

Add this dependency

```
    implementation 'com.github.dnsjava:dnsjava:3.2.2'
```

Dns Class

```
class CustomDns : Dns {

private fun lookupFrom(hostname: String): List<InetAddress> {
    val simpleResolver = SimpleResolver(GOOGLE_DNS);
    val addresses = mutableListOf<InetAddress>()

    val lookup = Lookup(hostname)
    lookup.setResolver(simpleResolver)
    val arrayOfRecords = lookup.run()
    if (arrayOfRecords != null)
        for (record in arrayOfRecords)
            if (record.type == Type.A)
                addresses += ((record as ARecord).address)

    val lookup1 = Lookup(hostname, Type.AAAA)
    lookup1.setResolver(simpleResolver)
    val arrayOfRecords1 = lookup1.run()
    if (arrayOfRecords1 != null)
        for (record in arrayOfRecords1)
            if (record.type == Type.AAAA)
                addresses += ((record as AAAARecord).address)

    if (addresses.size < 1)
        throw UnknownHostException("Host '$hostname' unknown to '$GOOGLE_DNS'")
    return addresses
}

override fun lookup(hostname: String): List<InetAddress> {
    return try {
        try {
            InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname).toList()  // 1. try: original to system library
        } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
            try {
                Address.getAllByName(hostname).toList()  // 2. try: DNSJava default lookup
            } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                lookupFrom(hostname)  // fallback: tailored lookup via DNSJava
            }
        }
    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        throw UnknownHostException("Broken system behaviour for dns lookup of $hostname").apply {
            initCause(e)
        }
    }
}

companion object{
    private const val GOOGLE_DNS = "8.8.8.8"
}}
```

I used Hilt to provide this DNS with OKHttp Client. You can setup according to your project setup.

```
object CustomOkHttpClient {

private val customDns = CustomDns()

val instance: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .dns(customDns)
    // Add any other OkHttpClient customization if needed
    .build()}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was facing a similar issue while using Volley in android. The issue got resolved after invalidating the cache and restarting the project.

In Android Studio,
File -> Invalidate Caches -> Select all checkboxes -> Invalidate cache and Restart.

Comment: the question is relation to user's device not the Android Studio itself.